# JavaScript blur event -- is there any way to detect which element now has focus?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Does anyone have a technique that will allow me to determine which element has focus after a `blur` event? I have an input field which I'd like to reset on `blur` *unless* the `blur` was caused by the user clicking the <kbd>save</kbd> button. I'd love to just set a flag in the <kbd>save</kbd> button's `onclick` function, but that would fire too late (unless `click` events always fire before `blur` events, which I doubt.)

Comment: On the other subject I saw only hacks, but there's actually a builtin solution very easy to use :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement

Basically you can capture the focus element like this:
`const focusedElement = document.activeElement`
and you're good to go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered here; [**When onblur occurs, how can I find out which element focus went *to*?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to)