# In Dojo or Javascript how do I make my event handler fire before other event handlers?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dojo

In the Dojo Javascript library, I understand how to use dojo.connect or dojo.publish to wire up my event handler to an event. That functionality works great.

But I want to do one additional thing.

I want my event handler to fire first, before any other already defined event handlers. I suppose this could be called "event handler insertion" or something.

Is there a way to do that in Dojo or a convenient and elegant way in plain Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your event like this:

```
function alertTest(){
    alert('test');
}

function alertTest2(){
    alert('test2');
}

window.onload = alertTest2; //just setting it to simulate that an event
                            //is already set

oldOnload = window.onload; //store the old event into a temporary variable
window.onload = function() { //assign a new function to the event
    alertTest(); //whatever your "must happen first" function is
    oldOnload.apply(); //run the original event after
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When events are fired they are connected to their *action* (onload, onclick). So how would you fire an event before other actions are triggered?

For example, how would you fire an event before an `onclick` if you don't know when it's going to be triggered ?

This is definitely something you *can't* do, maybe you want to register handlers to the `onload` event which is usually triggered before all the others.

Answer (score 0):

I had a (possibly) related problem, and wound up using setTimeout to set a flag.

[javascript blur event -- is there any way to detect which element now has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528208/javascript-blur-event-is-there-any-way-to-detect-which-element-now-has-focus)
ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, once the event handlers are attached to the DOM node, the sequence of handlers execution is implementation dependent.