# Onblur, what is the next control which will gain focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am firing some code onblur() of a textbox. But I want to do something different if the user clicked on the cancel button to cause that onblur(). Is there a way within the onblur() event handler function to know what the control is that is about to receive focus and react acordingly?

-Joseph

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can get the target like this:

```
var target = event.explicitOriginalTarget || document.activeElement;
```

(I think I found this on StackOverflow somewhere).

Comment: Here is the related discussion - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to but the accepted answer only works in IE, not in Firefox (3.6)

Comment: I haven't tested it in many browsers, but I think you misunderstood. The way I read that just now, this works in all Firefox browsers except for 3.6. So it sounds like a bug they will be fixing soon in 3.6 perhaps. Plus, I believe (without having verified) that it works   on Safari, Opera, etc.

Comment: The author of the accepted answer in the other thread posted a reply to my comment. It does work in 3.6 but with a caveat. He also says it doesn't work in webkit browsers at all.

Comment: I am using just IE, so this works great for me. I tested it out, and it works like a champ! On my validation framework (jquery validation) I just check if the target button ends with the phrase "Cancel" 

        onfocusout: function(element) {
            var target = document.activeElement;
            if (target != null && target.id.match(/Cancel$/)) {
                return true;
            }

Comment: Glad to hear it. I also am on an IE project, and it has been pretty thoroughly tested in our product for about a month now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built in way, but you can hack together something by attaching `focus` events to all the form elements and setting some globally accessible variable about who received focus.

Something like this (you may want to fine-tune the time values):

```
var focusedElem = null;
var focusedTime = 0;

$("input", "#myForm").focus(function() {
    focusedElem = this;
    focusedTime = new Date();
})
.blur(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { //set a small timeout to wait for the other control to receive focus and set itself as focusedElem
        if (focusedElem && (new Date() - focusedTime) < 15) {
            //do Something with focusedElem;
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

Comment: Ify, but that seems to be the case.