# How to determine which element gets focus in blur()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is it possible to find the element that currently has the focus in a cross-browser way?

In IE, it is possible to do `$(x).blur(function(evt) { alert('Focus goes to ' + evt.toElement.id); });` and I need to do something similar in other browsers.

As an alternative, if its possible, I could do a `setTimeout` and then investigate the currently focused element, but I don't know to do that either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When onblur occurs, how can I find out which element focus went \*to\*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to)

Answer (score 0):

You could just remember what was focused in a variable. Variable scope in JS works cross-browser :)

```
(function($){

var focused;
$(commonParentForElements).on('focus','input',function(e){
  focused = e.target;
}).on('blur','input',function(e){
  //do stuff with focused
  //when done, clean up
  focused = null;
})

})(jQuery);
```