# Submit shouldn't blur textarea with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur

I have a textarea with a blur function:

```
$("#comment").blur(function() {
        ...something
    });
```

I don't want this `blur()` to happen when I click on the submit button below. How can I solve this?

Comment: do u have any other code (for the submit for example)

Comment: no it's anormal form! submit happens when clicking `<input type="submit">`

Comment: lol so a normal submit is a **PAGE REFRESH** so ur blur() code will get called agian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried taking a look at [When onblur occurs, how can I find out which element focus went *to*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to) -- it should help in this case so you can determine whether to fire the 'blur' function or not based on where the focus **went to**

Answer (score 0):

a normal submit is a **PAGE REFRESH**

So: when your page loads again, the `blur()` code will get called as well

Answer (score 0):

In your submit pass a variable back to the server in the form that indicates that it was a form submit (ie a meaningful flag). When you re-render the page render it with the flag, stating it was a form submit, in javascript. Look for that flag in your blur handler, clear it,  and return false.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var _commentBlurTimer = 0;
$("#comment").blur(function() {
   _commentBlurTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
      //...something
   }, 500);
});

$("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
   if (_commentBlurTimer)
      window.clearTimeout(_commentBlurTimer);
});
```

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/a9xZW/