# How to determine where focus went?

Tags: javascript, html, focus, onblur

This has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to) before, but several years ago, and there was no cross-platform solution at the time (other than the `setTimeout` solution, which is really not very handy).

I'd like to do `onblur="foo(parm);"` and have `foo` be able to determine which element now has focus.

I'm using regular javascript; no jQuery for this one, please.

Is that possible these days?

Comment: Well it is doable in jQuery, which means it's doable in Javascript. I have no idea though, good question. +1

Comment: Hmmm. Can you post the jQuery in an answer and maybe I can work backwards from that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When onblur occurs, how can I find out which element focus went *to*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to)

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, I mentioned that in the post, but the answers at the time were not cross-platform.

Comment: @Daniel: I asking if the technology has changed, if there's an answer today. Please remove the close vote. Please... :)

Comment: There's nothing not handy about `setTimeout`. It's the best solution, and the only one which actually works. All the others fail because the "active element" when the blur event is fired is not yet the one that was clicked or tabbed to: it will only receive the focus following another event, when the blur event's processing's done!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function whereDidYouGo() {
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

        for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
            if (all[i] === all[i].ownerDocument.activeElement)
                return all[i];
}
```

EDIT:

```
function whereDidYouGo() { return document.activeElement; }
```

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. Doing some reading on `activeElement`. Wouldn't I just be able to do `elementWithFocus=document.activeElement;` ?

Comment: @JonathanM: lol, yup, I just grabbed jQuery's `:focus` filter

Comment: Yes, I think so. This seems to show it: http://help.dottoro.com/external/examples/ljmiswgp/activeElement_1.htm

Comment: Mod your answer to reflect, and I'll check it. Thanks, qwertymk.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks much. Good teamwork between you and Rikudo. :) Give him some upvotes. :D

Comment: Do ALL current browsers have - at the moment of the blur event - the activeElement?

Comment: @WolfgangAdamec -- apparently not.  In some browsers, I'm getting the `body` returned if I don't use setTimeout.  In IE8, no timeout needed.  In FF 18.0.1, setTimeout **is** needed.  In Chrome, it looks like an anchor doesn't get focus.  [jsfiddle-ige](http://jsfiddle.net/UtDLS/2/)

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery, at the OP's request:

```
$(':input').blur(function() {
    $focusedElement = $(':input:focus');
    //Do stuff with $focusedElement
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Rikudo. It's a starting point. Anyone have ideas on how to devolve this to regular javascript?

Comment: @Daniel: In the comments, I asked for this as a starting point. It's cool.

Comment: You are better off using jQuery or some other JavaScript library because the good ones are functional across multiple browsers.

Comment: @DwB: Yes, but the `activeElement` solution accepted here is also cross-platform, so it's a legit way to go. If interested, see: http://help.dottoro.com/ljmiswgp.php

Comment: Doesn't work in latest Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.  The heart of the matter is - when does the 'focus' event fire, before or after the blur event?  If it fires before the blur event, the problem is easy, because you can just store the current focus in a variable that your blur event can access.

However, at least in Chrome 13, it appears the blur event happens *before* the focus event.  One possible solution.

Given the following HTML:

```
<input id="foo" value='foo' />
<input id="bar" value='bar' />
```

You can then:

```
var currentFocus;
var pendingBlur;

var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
foo.addEventListener('focus', function(){ 
    currentFocus = foo;
    if(pendingBlur !== undefined){
        pendingBlur();
        pendingBlur = undefined;
    }
});
foo.addEventListener('blur', function(){
    pendingBlur = function(){
        console.log('new focus:', currentFocus);
    };
});

var bar= document.getElementById('bar');
bar.addEventListener('focus', function(){ 
   currentFocus = bar;
   if(pendingBlur !== undefined){
        pendingBlur();
        pendingBlur = undefined;
   }
});
bar.addEventListener('blur', function(){
    pendingBlur = function(){
        console.log('new focus:', currentFocus);
    };
});
```

Basically, I just not the blur callback so it is handy for the focus event to call after we know about which element was focused.

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/BaYJu/) on JSFiddle.

EDIT: This solution suffers from the problem that if you blur on the form by clicking on something *other* than another form element, the blur event never fires (since we wait for the focus event).  The only way around that, that I can conceive, is using a timer to check if pendingBlur is defined, and if so, call it.  At which point you don't really need the focus event to call the blur callback anymore...

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I'll have to digest this after lunch. :)

Comment: +1 for considering the timing of `blur()` vs. `focus()` and testing it on chrome. However, a perhaps better approach to dealing with the lag between `blur()` and `focus()` may be to employ a `setTimeout()` with the function called by `onblur`.

Comment: @Jonathan M, yes, I'd be inclined to use a timeout.  I just avoided it given your request in the question :)

Comment: Sorry to throw you off of that. I wasn't necessarily against using setTimeout(), just the solution that involved it. That solution requires setting a variable for every `onclick`...very messy. Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Year 2020: All major browsers (desktop and mobile) support [FocusEvent.relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget).

Answer (score 0):

`event.relatedTarget` couldn't find the newly-focused element(was `div` type in my case), but only `null` gets returned.

After attaching the attribute `tabindex="0"` on the element, now it works.

```html
<div id="myDiv">myDiv</div>
console.log(e.relatedTarget) // null

<div id="myDiv" tabindex="0"> tabindexed div </div>
console.log(e.relatedTarget) // <div id="myDiv" tabindex="0">
```

`tabindex` is an attribute that make elements focusable using tab key on keyboard. I guess it is mainly for web accessibility.

And I guess you won't need to set `tabindex` attribute as long as to-be focused elements are already accessible by tab key (such as `a`, `select`.. and so on)

Comment: In the latest Chrome, even after adding a tabindex attribute it does not work. However, for me it was the HTML 'button' element on which I was setting the tabindex and wanted the relatedTarget to contain the reference to. However, it's still null.