# Crossbrowser method to determine anchor tag selected to cause textarea blur

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

There are a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/a/121708/1028230) good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096120/how-to-determine-where-focus-went) on here regarding how to determine where focus goes 'concurrent' to a textarea `onblur`.

But I haven't found a good cross-browser way to determine which anchor tag has been clicked which caused a textarea to fire `onblur`, `setTimeout` or no.  `document.activeElement` looked promising, but, answers seemingly to the contrary, without a `setTimeout`, `activeElement` is unreliable.  I keep getting the `body` returned as the `activeElement` in some browsers.

For example:
[jsFiddle-ige #1](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5kcp/):

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input onblur="blurHandler();" type="text" id="spam1" 
        value="immediate blur check">
    <input onblur="blurHandlerTimeout();" type="text" id="spam2" 
        value="delayed blur check"> 
    <a href="#" id="spam3">X</a>
    <br>
</form>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<div id="logs"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var logs = document.getElementById('logs');

function blurHandler() {
    logit(document.activeElement.outerHTML.substr(0, 80));
}

function blurHandlerTimeout() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        logit(document.activeElement.outerHTML.substr(0, 80));
    }, 10);
}

function logit(msg) {
    try {
        var e = document.createTextNode(msg), // probably a better way, but this does allow html as text
            f = document.createElement('div');

        logs.insertBefore(e, logs.firstChild);
        logs.insertBefore(f, logs.firstChild);
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

**Body element for blur from the immediate blur check textbox occurs every time for the following:**

- Safari 5.1.7 (which doesn't let me focus on the anchor at all,
  tabbing or clicking)
- Firefox 18.0.1
- Chrome 24.0.1312.56 m,

Setting focus to the **delayed** blur check box and clicking/tabbing into the anchor gives me:

- Chrome: the **body** if click the anchor
- Chrome: the **anchor** if I tab into it
- Safari: the **body** either way
- Firefox: the **anchor** no matter what

**IE8 gives me the anchor every time** for each textbox, delayed handler or no.

So admittedly there are ways to have the anchor set a boolean at a shared scope level (eg, a global) and have a setTimeout from the blur event query that boolean to see if the anchor [recently] got focus, but man oh man that's kludgey.

That said, I did it, give or take, here: [jsFiddle-ige #2](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5kcp/2/)  Seems to work okay there in all four, though I'm afraid it's going to be edge-case crazy.

Is there better way to do this?  jQuery's fine, I guess, though I'd prefer a clean JavaScript solution -- which is to say that a clean jQuery solution is better than convoluted JavaScript fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delayed check for [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.activeElement) works in all browsers as long as you specify a `tabindex` attribute on the anchor tag. `a`, by default, has no tabbing order, so I'd argue that those browsers that are able to "focus" the `a` at all without that attribute are misbehaving.

Per the [HTML5 spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#attr-tabindex):

> **The tabindex content attribute allows authors to control whether an element is supposed to be focusable**, whether it is supposed to be reachable using sequential focus navigation, and what is to be the relative order of the element for the purposes of sequential focus navigation.

*(Emphasis mine)*

```
<form>
    <input onblur="blurHandler();" type="text" id="spam1" 
        value="immediate blur check">
    <input onblur="blurHandlerTimeout();" type="text" id="spam2" 
        value="delayed blur check"> 
    <a href="#" id="spam3" tabindex='1'>X</a>
    <br>
</form>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<div id="logs"></div>
```

**Updated fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Y5kcp/4/

Tested in IE8/9, FF 18.0.1, Chrome 24.0.1312.56 m, Safari 5.17

This is pure speculation, but maybe IE was behaving nicely because the [HTML4 spec for `tabindex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex) doesn't mention "focusability" as a feature:

> This attribute specifies the position of the current element in the tabbing order for the current document.

In that case, maybe browsers adhering to the HTML 4 specification are okay allowing the anchor tag to be focusable with or without the tabindex attribute.

It's also worth noting that `document.activeElement` was a proprietary IE4 feature (see **Notes** on the MDN article for `document.activeElement`). Maybe that's why it'll function without the timeout in Internet Explorer.