# jquery function blur() unless if click on an element with id="toto"

Tags: jquery, blur

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When onblur occurs, how can I find out which element focus went *to*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to)

I have a jquery function that allows me to do something when an element (here selectionChamp) loses focus:

```
$("#selectionChamp").blur(function() {      
    $("#detailChamp").attr('disabled', true, 'enabled', false);
    $("#supprChamp").attr('disabled', true, 'enabled', false);      
});
```

I would like to add a condition for the function to do something when you lose focus unless you click on an element with another id. (id="toto" for example !^^)

An idea?

Comment: The #selectionChamp will limit the function to elements with an Id of selectionChamp, so you can't have an element with a different Id - did you mean to use a class instead?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to.

Comment: @Frederic not only related, it is THE answer.