# Skip onblur event for CKEditor only

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ckeditor

I have a java script function which fires on `onblur()` event of the body.

```
  function start() {
                var el = document.getElementById('divWarning');
                el.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
```

Fires on:

```
<body onblur="start()">
```

It's working fine on every page. Except the one in which I have included a CKEditor.

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="txtDescriptiveAnswer" runat="server" Width="75%" UIColor="#54b2ff" BorderColor="#007cdf" BorderWidth="2px" Toolbar="Source|-|Preview
                                                                        Bold|Italic|Underline|Strike|-|Subscript|Superscript
                                                                        JustifyLeft|JustifyCenter|JustifyRight|JustifyBlock
                                                                        NumberedList|BulletedList|-|Outdent|Indent|Blockquote|Styles|Format|Font|FontSize|TextColor|BGColor|Maximize"  BasePath="../ckeditor">
                            </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

Every time I click on CKeditor to write somthing, The onblur event fires up. I know that CkEditor have an IFrame which is I think making the problem. But I don't know how to skip the blur event for CkEditor only.

Please help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/AHzgt/). You can eventually enhance this filter and search for a particular `name`, `id`, `tagName` etc. Also check [When onblur occurs, how can I find out which element focus went *to*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to) thread for more information about your problem since there are many techniques of handling it.

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work in my case.
What I am trying to achieve that onblur event shoud not fire when I click on ckeditor. The text area part in ckeditor is not actually an IFRAME but an complete html in iframe.

Comment: @kakarott I'm not quite sure what you're actually trying to accomplish. Since you can detect where does the focus go `onblur` (the sample I provided), you can avoid executing your code (`start()`) when focusing CKEditor instance or any other element. This is a very simple filtering.