# OnBlur event in backbone

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am using the blur action with backbone. In my backbone view I have

```
var EventView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:  "li",

    template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),

    events: {
      "click .toggle"   : "toggleDone",
      "dblclick .view"  : "edit",
      "click a.destroy" : "clear",
      "keypress .edit"  : "updateOnEnter",
      "blur .edit"      : "close"
    },

    initialize: function() {
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
    },

    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
      this.$el.toggleClass('done', this.model.get('done'));
      this.form = this.$(".edit");
      this.input = this.$(".edit-title");
      this.eventLeaders = this.$('.edit-leaders');
      this.eventDescription = this.$('.edit-description');
      return this;
    },

    toggleDone: function() {
      this.model.toggle();
    },

    edit: function() {
      this.$el.addClass("editing");
      this.form.focus();
    },

    close: function() {

      if (!this.input.val()) {
        this.clear();
      } else {
        this.model.save({
                    title: this.input.val(), 
                    description: this.eventDescription.val(),
                    leaders: this.eventLeaders.val().split(/[, ]+/)});
        this.$el.removeClass("editing");
      }
    },

    updateOnEnter: function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) this.close();
    },

    clear: function() {
      this.model.destroy();
    }

});
```

In my HTML I have:

```
  <script type="text/template" id="item-template">
    <div class="view">
      <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" <%= done ? 'checked="checked"' : '' %> />
      <label><%- title %></label>
      <div class="details">
        <span class="description"><p><%- description %></p>Leaders:</span>
        <% _.each(leaders, function(leader){ %>
          <span class="event-leader"> <%= leader %> </span>
        <% }); %>
      </div>
      <a class="destroy"></a>
    </div>
    <form class="edit">
      <input class="edit-title" type="text" value="<%- title %>" />
      <input class="edit-description" type="text" value="<%- description %>" />
      <input class="edit-leaders" type="text" value="<%= leaders.join(', ') %>" />
    </form>
  </script>
```

and in my CSS I have:

```
#event-list li.editing .edit {
    display: block;
    width: 444px;
    padding: 13px 15px 14px 20px;
    margin: -30px;
}

#event-list li.editing .view {
    display: none;
}
#event-list li .edit {
    display: none;
}
```

The problem I have is the blur event is fired when I switch between editing different textboxes and I am not sure why. Even when I use tab to switch between text boxes. I don't want this to be the default behavior. How can I change this?

Comment: The blur event is raised when an element loses focus. So when you switch between textboxes, it's fired...!

Comment: But I put the blur event to act on when my form loses focus, not when my input boxes lose focus?

Comment: Is the blur event on `<form>` generally supported by browsers? The [latest working draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#handler-onblur) suggests that all HTML elements support it but...

Comment: I'm not sure. I was hoping it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a selector in your `events` -hash like this

```
'blur <the event designator> .edit <the selector>': 'onBlur'
```

The backbone.js `delegateEvents` uses the jQuery `on` -function to bind events like [this](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-169)

```
this.$el.on(eventName, selector, method);
```

However, there's a gotcha, that can be found from the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on the `on` -function and its parameters

> **selector**
>
> Type: String
>
> A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

Somehow when the selector is included, the eventhandler catches the events propagating from the children of the element (in this case the inputs). Without the selector, the events are not caught (i made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9bvUS/) to demonstrate, open your console and toggle the different inputs). Quick playing around with my fiddle also revealed it to be nigh impossible to detect wether or not the form had focus.

This is why the blur event is triggered by the input fields. As to how to detect when your form loses focus: it is hard to say, because browsers decide for themselves, which elements they allow focus to be given to. Here are some stackoverflow sources i found, but failed to get to work in the fiddle:

[Using jQuery to test if an input has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus)

[When onblur occurs, how can I find out which element focus went *to*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to)