# jQuery event only if two elements are not focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a FIRST NAME and a LAST NAME text field. I want to display a line of text when either of them are focused and hide the line of text only when both elements are not focused.

My current code flips the text (hides then unhides) whenever I change focus from say the first name to the last.

I understand why, first name is getting blurred (triggering the hide animation) then last name gets the focus (triggering the show animation). This is undesirable for obvious reasons, I'm looking for an elegant fix.

HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First" id="first" name="first" required>
<input type="text" placeholder="Last" id="last" name="last" required>
<p id="nameTxt" style="display: none">Blah blah blah</p>
```

Script

```
    $('#first, #last').focus(function() { $("#nameTxt").show(300); });
    $('#first, #last').blur(function() { $("#nameTxt").hide(150); });
```

Comment: See if this helps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement

Comment: possible duplicate of [When onblur occurs, how can I find out which element focus went \*to\*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to)

Comment: I disagree, where's the button for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var timerID;
$('#first, #last').focus(function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    $("#nameTxt").show(300);
}).blur(function() {
    timerID = setTimeout(function() {
        $("#nameTxt").hide(150);
    }, 10);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VBwYE/

That is, use `setTimeout()` to defer hiding the `#nameTxt` for just a few milliseconds, but then in the focus handler cancel the timeout. Note that you can chain `.focus().blur()` together to avoid having to select the same two elements again.

Comment: This works well, thanks! Just kind of wish we didn't have to use such a hackish method. :/

Comment: You're welcome. If you wait somebody else may have a more direct solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting one! Here's a thought. You could do something like this:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(){
  if ($(event.target).attr("id") != "first" && $(event.target).attr("id") != "last") {
    // hide it
  }
  else{
    //show it
  }
});
```

Would only work for clicks though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#first, #last").blur(function() {
    if ($("#first:focus, #last:focus").length == 0) {
        $("#nameTxt").hide(150);
    }
});
```

Comment: This still caused the hide/show jag when changing from first to last.

Comment: Results for testing the focus might vary depending on the browser (not all browsers trigger focus/blur/change events in the same order).

Comment: I think that's the problem. When you click from one to the other, it first blurs the old field, then focuses the new field. So when the `blur()` handler runs, neither field is focused.

Comment: I think I researched this a few months ago, and the specification requires that behavior. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to for workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $nt = $("#nameTxt");
$('#first, #last').focus(function () {
    clearTimeout($nt.data('nttimer'))
    $("#nameTxt").show(300);
});
$('#first, #last').blur(function () {
    var timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#nameTxt").hide(150);
    }, 200);
    $nt.data('nttimer', timer);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UnjnN/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
<script>
    $('#first, #last').focus(function() { $("#nameTxt").show(300); });
    $('#first, #last').on("blur focusout", function() { $("#nameTxt").hide(150); });   
</script>
```

Because some browser is not support blur event.

Comment: _"Because some browser is not support blur event"_ - Which browsers would that be? Either way this doesn't help with the problem the OP described.

Comment: I mean IE8 and some older browser.

Comment: IE has supported blur events since at least version 5.5.

Comment: I read it on jquery page: "The blur event does not bubble in Internet Explorer. Therefore, scripts that rely on event delegation with the blur event will not work consistently across browsers. As of version 1.4.2, however, jQuery works around this limitation by mapping blur to the focusout event in its event delegation methods, .live() and .delegate()."

Comment: "The blur event does not bubble in IE" means that the blur event _is_ supported in IE, it just doesn't bubble. Which doesn't matter at all for the OP's code which does not use bubbling. So I say again, IE has supported blur since at least v5.5. And, again, this is all irrelevant to the actual problem the OP described.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. Thanks for advice. I'll delete my answer