# Is it possible to get clicked element with on-blur listener?

Tags: javascript, events, onblur

I have a form with on blur listener, when I click outside the form and the blur triggered, can I get the element that was clicked on?

Comment: Not without a `click` listener as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/121708/1640090

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the element that triggered any event with `event.target`, but you need to set up an event handler for that event.  As @adeneo said, you'd need to set up a `click` event handler that would fire no matter where you might click. You could do this by setting the handler on `document.click`. However, this will fire even if you have clicked inside your form. You'd need to do some validation on the clicked element to be sure it's one that you are interested in.

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvawtf4a/) (open your console developer tool)