# How to hide a dropdown when the user clicks outside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, drop-down-menu

Below is a simplified version of the input dropdown I am working with.

A basic summary of what it does is: if you focus on the input, a dropdown appears. If you click one of the options in the dropdown, the option populates the input and the dropdown disappears. This is achieved using `onfocus` and a functions I called `dropdown();` and `undropdown();`.

I'm in a dilemma, where I'm unable to make the dropdown disappear when someone clicks elsewhere. If I use `onblur`, it successfully hides the dropdown, but if you click on an option it doesn't populate the input, this is because, the `onblur` function runs first and, therefore, the `input();` function doesn't not run because the dropdown is already hidden.

If you put an `onclick` on the body tag, or other parent, it considers the `onfocus` as a click, where it run's the `dropdown();` function then the `undropdown();` function immediately so the dropdown never appears since the functions overlap.

I would appreciate help on figuring out how to order the functions so that they are executed in the right order without overlapping with each other.

JSFiddle available [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/akq94885/)

```js
function input(pos) {
  var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('drop');
  var li = dropdown[0].getElementsByTagName("li");
  document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = li[pos].innerHTML;
  undropdown(0);
}
function dropdown(pos) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('content')[pos].style.display = "block"
}
function undropdown(pos) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('content')[pos].style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.drop {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: visible;
}
.content {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 190px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.content li {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop">
  <input type="text" name="class" placeholder="Class" onfocus="dropdown(0)"/>
  <ul class="content">
    <li onclick="input(0)">Option 1</li>
    <li onclick="input(1)">Option 2</li>
    <li onclick="input(2)">Option 3</li>
    <li onclick="input(3)">Option 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

PS: In addition to the above problem, I would appreciate suggestion for edits to get a better title for this question such that someone experiencing a similar problem could find it more easily.

Comment: Might be helpful to repro the problem in www.jsfiddle.net (easier to work with and come up with a solution) - title is probably fine, generic enough to work with many problems but describes yours pretty accurately.

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't use `<select>`?

Comment: Usually you trap clicks on (or propagated to) the document element and close the dropdown if necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, On `onblur` you could call a function which fires the `undropdown(0);` after a very tiny setTimeout almost instantly. Like so:

```
function set() {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    undropdown(0);
  }, 100);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="class" placeholder="Class" onfocus="dropdown(0)" onblur="set()" />
```

No other change is required.

```js
function input(pos) {
  var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('drop');
  var li = dropdown[0].getElementsByTagName("li");

  document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = li[pos].innerHTML;
  undropdown(0);
}

function dropdown(pos) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('content')[pos].style.display= "block"
}

function undropdown(pos) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('content')[pos].style.display= "none";
}

function set() {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    undropdown(0);
  }, 100);
}
```

```css
        .drop {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align:top;
            overflow: visible;
        }

        .content {
            display: none;
            list-style-type: none;
            border: 1px solid #000; 
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            width: 100%;
            max-height: 190px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        .content li {
            padding: 12px 16px;
            display: block;
            margin: 0;
        }
```

```html
   <div class="drop">
        <input type="text" name="class" placeholder="Class" onfocus="dropdown(0)" onblur="set()" />
        <ul class="content">
            <li onclick="input(0)">Option 1</li>
            <li onclick="input(1)">Option 2</li>
            <li onclick="input(2)">Option 3</li>
            <li onclick="input(3)">Option 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: One issue with this solution is that if the user clicks slowly (mousedown + mouseup takes longer than 100ms) the option will not be selected. You can try clicking slowly on the demo to see it in action.

Answer (score 7):

You could make the dropdown focusable with `tabindex`, and in the input's `blur` event listener only hide the dropdown if the focus didn't go to the dropdown (see [When onblur occurs, how can I find out which element focus went *to*?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33325953/1529630))

```html
<ul class="content" tabindex="-1"></ul>
```

```js
input.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
  if(!e.relatedTarget || !e.relatedTarget.classList.contains('content')) {
    undropdown(0);
  }
});
```

```js
function input(e) {
  var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('drop');
  var li = dropdown[0].getElementsByTagName("li");
  document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = e.target.textContent;
  undropdown(0);
}
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('li'), function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', input);
});
function dropdown(pos) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('content')[pos].style.display = "block"
}
function undropdown(pos) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('content')[pos].style.display = "none";
}
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
input.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
  dropdown(0);
});
input.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
  if(!e.relatedTarget || !e.relatedTarget.classList.contains('content')) {
    undropdown(0);
  }
});
```

```css
.drop {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: visible;
}
.content {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 190px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  outline: none;
}
.content li {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop">
  <input type="text" name="class" placeholder="Class" />
  <ul class="content" tabindex="-1">
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
    <li>Option 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer is a naive and unreliable approach. I had a hard-to-catch bug in a complex application because I used a `setTimeout` to give ~200ms delay so the browser can process dropdown click before blur event happens. While it worked great on every setup I tested it with, some users did have issues, in particular users with slower machines.

The correct way is to test `relatedTarget` on `focusout` event:

```
input.addEventListener('focusout', function(event) {
  if(!isDropdownElement(event.relatedTarget)) {
    // hide dropdown
  }
});
```

`relatedTarget` for `focusout` contains an [element reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget), which is receiving focus. This reliably works in every browser I've tested so far (I didn't test IE10 and lower, only IE11 and Edge).

Answer (score 0):

W3Schools has a nice example of how to create a custom dropdown:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

This is how the focus is handled in that example:

A global click-handler handles clicks outside of the dropdown list: `document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);`. So as soon as the user clicks anywhere in the document, all dropdowns are closed.

But when the user selects an element of the dropdown list, the click-event is stopped by `e.stopPropagation();` inside of the selection-handler.

This way, you don´t need the timer workaround.