# Javascript get Element clicked on in onClickEvent

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using React, and have the following setup:

```
<input onBlur={(e) => {this.removeEditable(e)}} //...etc
/>
```

and

```
removeEditable(e) {    
//Do Something
  }
```

My problem is that I am trying to get the element clicked on from the event fired `onBlur`. Please note, this may not be the same element as the element that originated the click. For example, the `input` box above may be active, but the onblur event will get fired when the user clicks outside of the `input` box.

I have tried `event.target` but that gives the input element defined above - not the element that the actual click happened on.

Can this be done?

I am pretty sure for drag and drop this can be done but not sure about blur?

I have tried `event.currentTarget` as was previously suggested below (and then removed), but that also returns the input element, in the same was as event.target does.

As a note, the element that is being clicked on is position absolute, and overlaid on top of a div without position type defined (eg standard position) - I am not sure if this could be affecting the event?

I have logged the `event.currentTarget` and it seems to always return the input outlined above.

Comment: The `onblur` event actually only appears on the input element, not on the element you clicked on.

Comment: `I am trying to get the element clicked on from the event fired onBlur` - See answers in top result from google search on `get the element clicked on from the event fired onBlur` ► [**When onblur occurs, how can I find out which element focus went *to*?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to) Hope it helps.

Comment: @Christoph I know that, but onBlur is only triggered when the input element is in focus

Comment: So I don't get the question to be honest. You cannot get the element you clicked on from a  `blur` event, you need the `click` event for this. Also, what happens if the user does not click, but tabs to the next element - then you have no click event to begin with. You can try `document.activeElement` to see if another element got the focus though.

Comment: @Fran fair point - I could have googled that better

Comment: @Christoph Wouldn't the `focus` event trigger wether the user clicks on the input or tabs to it?

Comment: @Baruch This depends. For an `input` element, you are correct. But not every element emits a `focus` event and a click could be on a non-focus-able element, while tab automatically jumps to the next element that actually is able to receive focus.