# How to implement onBlur/onFocus for a div with nested input fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, onblur, onfocus

There is a `<div>` and a couple of nested `<input>`s. `onBlur` fires every time user clicks on one of the `<input>`s.
This is a bit frustrating that `onBlur` happens when I hit something inside the `div`. After an hour of searching I still wasn't able to find any good solution.
This sample of code shows what I'm talking about:

```
class Thing extends React.Component {
  handleBlur(e) {
    console.log('blur');
  }
  handleFocus(e) {
    console.log('focus');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onFocus={this.handleFocus} onBlur={this.handleBlur} tabIndex="1">
        <div>
          <input type="text" value="Hello," />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" value="Thing" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You may play around with the code [over here](https://codesandbox.io/s/qxrwGAm3D).
However my ultimate goal is to make [this thing](https://codesandbox.io/s/zz8P67Dy) working properly.

Comment: But what exactly do you want to achieve? They have to work separately?

Comment: @Kinduser it would be nice if onBlur wouldn't happen when user hits anything inside of the `<div>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding on to this with what I think is the best solution these days.

This ignores blur events by using the [Node.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) method to check whether the element is a descendant of that which is already focused.

```js
handleBlur({ currentTarget, relatedTarget }) {
   if (currentTarget.contains(relatedTarget)) return;

   /* otherwise normal actions to perform on blur */

   console.log('blur');
}
handleFocus(e) {
   console.log('focus');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to ignore extra blur events.

```
handleBlur(e) {
   if (e.target.tagName == "INPUT") {
      return;
   }
   console.log('blur');
}
handleFocus(e) {
   console.log('focus');
}
```

Comment: That seems to be a good approach, it would be a perfect solution if I could define if the e.target is one of the child elements of the `<div>`

Comment: @dmigo Accessing DOM strictly through `target` isn't a good solution, especially in React.

Comment: @Kinduser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to) guys suggest a bit more sophisticated approach than just using `target`. What do you think about it?

Comment: @dmigo This solution is 9 years old. Check: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @Kinduser [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/vo2opP0Nn) worked out for me. Not sure if it might be considered as a clean solution though. Basically, I just check on every `blur` event if `e.relativeTarget` has `e.currentTarget` anywhere in the `parentElement` chain.

Answer (score 1):

How about splitting the inputs into a single, independent component?

`app.js`

```
class Thing extends React.Component {
  handleBlur(val, event) {
    console.log(val, event);
  }
  handleFocus(val, event) {
    console.log(val, event);
  }

  data = ['Hello, ', 'Thing'];

  render() {
    return (
      <div tabIndex="1">
        {this.data.map((v, i) => <Input value={v} key={i} onFocus={this.handleFocus} onBlur={this.handleBlur} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`Input.js`

```
import React from 'react';

export class Input extends React.PureComponent {

  handleF = () => {
    this.props.onFocus(this.props.value, 'focus');
  }

  handleB = () => {
    this.props.onBlur(this.props.value, 'blur');
  }

  render() {
    return <input type="text" onFocus={this.handleF} onBlur={this.handleB} />;
  }
}

export default Input;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/J6o5Ey9Jg

Comment: That looks nice, but that is not exactly what I want to achieve. My idea was to have a `<div>` that would keep focus, no mater what element inside of it is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

This is from OP comments above, he found the following solution which worked for him (and now me) and posted it in a comment.  I am reposting it here for anyone else who might not think to dig through comments.

> Basically, I just check on every blur event if e.relativeTarget has e.currentTarget anywhere in the parentElement chain.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vo2opP0Nn?file=/index.js