# relatedTarget is null in Firefox when onBlur is called

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to create a help message that will disappear when the user either clicks the toggle button to display the help message or clicks away by clicking elsewhere on the page. The solution appears to be to look at the `relatedTarget` property of the `onblur` event and prevent the `onblur` handler from running when the `relatedTarget` is the button to toggle the help message. This seems to work in Chrome, but in Firefox and Safari, the `relatedTarget` property is set to the container `div` rather than the button, which makes it impossible to distinguish between the toggle button click and a "click away".

I've created a simple demonstrator that illustrates the problem:

```js
let openState = false;
let contentDiv = document.getElementById("show-hide-content");
let accordionDiv = document.getElementById("accordion");
let showHideButton = document.getElementById("show-hide-toggle");
function setOpenState(state) {
    openState = state;
    if(openState) {
        contentDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
        contentDiv.focus();
    }
    else {
        contentDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}

function toggleVisibility(override) {
    if (typeof override === "boolean") {
        setOpenState(override);
    }
    else {
        setOpenState(!openState);
    }
}

function buttonClickHandler(event) {
    toggleVisibility();
}

function contentBlurHandler(event) {
    if(!accordionDiv.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
        toggleVisibility(false);
    }
}

showHideButton.onclick = buttonClickHandler;
contentDiv.onblur = contentBlurHandler;
```

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #409958;
}

.accordion {
    background-color: #28a7c9;
}

.show-hide-content {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #c91e63;
}
```

```html
<h1>Show/Hide Test</h1>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="drawer">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion">
      <button class="show-hide-toggle" id="show-hide-toggle">Show/Hide</button>
      <div class="show-hide-content" id="show-hide-content" tabindex="-1">
        <p>This is some content that should be shown or hidden depending on the toggle.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code works correctly in Chrome. However, in Firefox, clicking the "Show/Hide" button displays the hidden content, but doesn't hide it when the button is clicked again. As far as I can tell, this is because the `onblur` handler is hiding the div, and then the `onclick` handler is toggling it open again, even though I'm checking `onblur.relatedTarget` to ensure that it's not anywhere inside the drawer.

What is the correct way to detect click-away in Firefox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that [clicking the `<button>` doesn't focus it on some browser/OS combinations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Clicking_and_focus) (notably on macOS except in Chrome), so `onblur`'s `event.relatedTarget` is `null` as nothing on the page receives focus. If you SHIFT+TAB from the `<div id="show-hide-content">`, you'll see that `relatedTarget` is set as you expect, as the button does receive focus in this scenario.

I would run the code to hide the div off a small timeout, to give the `click` handler a chance to run first.

In the example below I implemented this suggestion and added some logging to make it easier to see what's going on:

```js
let openState = false;
let contentDiv = document.getElementById("show-hide-content");
let accordionDiv = document.getElementById("accordion");
let showHideButton = document.getElementById("show-hide-toggle");
function setOpenState(state) {
    openState = state;
    if(openState) {
        contentDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
        contentDiv.focus();
    }
    else {
        contentDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}

function buttonClickHandler(event) {
    console.log("click, setting openState to", !openState);
    setOpenState(!openState);
}

function contentBlurHandler(event) {
    console.log("blur, relatedTarget is", event.relatedTarget);

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("blur, after timeout, openState is", openState);
        setOpenState(false);
    }, 100);
}

showHideButton.onclick = buttonClickHandler;
showHideButton.onmousedown = function() {console.log("button mousedown"); };
contentDiv.onblur = contentBlurHandler;
showHideButton.onfocus = function(ev) { console.log("button onfocus"); }
```

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #409958;
}

.accordion {
    background-color: #28a7c9;
}

.show-hide-content {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #c91e63;
}
```

```html
<h1>Show/Hide Test</h1>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="drawer">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion">
      <button class="show-hide-toggle" id="show-hide-toggle">Show/Hide</button>
      <div class="show-hide-content" id="show-hide-content" tabindex="-1">
        <p>This is some content that should be shown or hidden depending on the toggle.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The missing piece for me was the `tabindex` property. I did some more digging after reading your answer and found that Firefox requires that the element receiving focus have a `tabIndex` in order for it to be populated as the `relatedTarget`. In the case of Firefox, setting the tabIndex on the `div` behind the button caused it to be populated as the `relatedTarget`, so I was able to redefine "clicking away" as "clicking outside the container div for the hidden content", and use that as a guard to prevent bouncing.

Comment: Oh, making the parent `div` focusable is clever! It is better than a timeout, as clicking slowly (with a pause between mousedown and a mouseup) breaks my solution..

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me as well on both Safari and Firefox.
I had an use case where I needed to show clear icon/button only when user focused input (with input having value of course). And clicking that icon would make a blur on input and I had check if new focused element is contained within input but since `relatedTarget` was null I could not check it.

I added dummy span around my clear button and `relatedTarget` wasnt't null anymore:

```
<span aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="outline: none;">
  <button>X</button>
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

For thoses who just need a specific value from the target, remember, if your application's design and size allows this possibility, that you can just hardcode the value:

```
onBlur={()=>function(value)}
```

For a lot of case it could just work, before an automatic, better scaling solution occurs you have this possibility.